# Outlook 2013 images in table

Tags: html, email, templates, outlook

I'm building an e-mail template and trying to add one line for social icons.

Without that social icons the e-mail fits in the window like that:

[image: without social icons]

If I resize the window, the e-mail resizes too.

But when I add theese social icons, the e-mail is bigger than the window:

[image: with social icons]

The html code for that line looks like:

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <a style="text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;" href="..." target="_blank">
            <img width="60" height="60" src="..." alt="LinkedIn" />
        </a>

        <a style="text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;" href="..." target="_blank">
            <img width="60" height="60" src="..." alt="Facebook" />
        </a>

        <a style="text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;" href="..." target="_blank">
            <img width="60" height="60" src="..." alt="Twitter" />
        </a>

        <a style="text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;" href="..." target="_blank">
            <img width="60" height="60" src="..." alt="Xing" />
        </a>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Does anybody know the reason why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the whitespaces are the problem? See [here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) for more